# How to import Google Takeout to Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have downloaded all my Chrome data from Google Takeout. Now, I want to import all of the search history since I started using Google to Firefox. Is there any tool, plugin or anything I can use to import the search history?

The history file is just 20 MB in size and it is in .json format

I also tried importing Chrome history with Firefox import tool but the duration of the history imported is only 6 months.

Comment: Perhaps there is no more than 6 months?

Comment: I guess you are right. I double checked my chrome history at activity.google.com and applied a filter before December, 31 2018 and there are no results. I thought search and chrome history are related but they don't. I think that's why the file is so large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your Chrome History is only good for about six months.
Official documentation does not guarantee more than 3 months.

The data you have imported to Firefox is all there is.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research and search ideas from harrymc, I've concluded that there is simply no way to import Google Takeout history to a web browser, not even Chrome.

> *"Google Takeout is an archiving tool, not a migration tool.  Most of the information you export can not be imported again." - bkc56*

Source:

- [Can I import the .json files from Takeout into a new Google Account?](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUZdFRijCmNtk/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fgmail%2FZdFRijCmNtk%2FdItjnhLZBQAJ&msgid=dItjnhLZBQAJ)
- [How do I import the BrowserHistory.json file and merge it with Vivaldi History?](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/24653/how-import-browserhistory-json-from-chrome-google-download/2)